# Getting the quotient $A/gcd(A,B)$ with the sub-resultant GCD algorithm

Tags: polynomials, gcd-and-lcm

The sub-resultant GCD algorithm allows to get the GCD of two polynomials $A$ and $B$ with coefficients in a UFD. Is it possible with this algorithm to get the quotients $A / gcd(A,B)$ and $B / gcd(A, B)$?

[image]